"No migration allowed after 60 days so we delete instead" policy
It was requested that migration of questions to other StackExchange sites be forbidden after 60 days due to some issues it causes with regards to points/reputation, and it appears that this was then implemented (e.g.). Deletion, on the other hand, remains possible past the 60-day limit.
I didn't know either of this, so I flagged an older question for migration from StackOverflow to SoftwareRecs, only to find later that it was deleted entirely, despite having some useful comments (maybe answers too, I don't remember and now I can't check anymore).
This seems like the most user-hostile way to handle this. I would've expected that, if migration is not possible, it just gets the closed-as-off-topic banner and that's it. Is deleting such questions the actual recommended policy?

I mean... closed questions are generally destined to be deleted. The only exception is when it has an upvoted answer and remains unnoticed by people with the ability to cast delete votes who would be willing to. The sample you've provided is a bit of an edge case. If you wanted to discuss it specifically... that'd probably be best done on MSO

Well… that sucks. I have forever wanted real deletion to be reserved for content actually harmful (or very new so minimal effort has been spent on it yet), and preferred closure+locking+delisting instead for handling older content. Unfortunately, that’s not where the community has landed.
